# Show that set is null set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X,\mathcal A)$. Let $(A_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of sets in $\mathcal A$ such that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\mu(A_k)<\infty$. Let $A:=\{x\in X:x\in A_k $for infinitely many $A_k\}$.
Show that $\mu(A)=0$ and that this does not hold if we don't ask for $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\mu(A_k)<\infty$.

My ideas:
Since $A\subseteq \cup_{k\in\mathbb N} A_k$ it follows that $\mu(A)\leq\mu(\cup_{k\in\mathbb N} A_k)\leq \sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\mu(A_k)<\infty$ so $\mu(A)$ is finite. My idea is to construct an infinite series of subsets of A with constant measure leading to a contradiction, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

I don't want a complete solution, just hints to guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Note, that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ we have
$$ A \subseteq \bigcup_{n \ge k} A_n $$
and hence $\mu(A) \le \sum_{n \ge k}\mu(A_n)$.

Comment: So since we can assume w.l.o.g. that $\mu(A_i)\geq\mu(A_{i+1})$ we have that $lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{n \ge k}\mu(A_n)=0$ and thus $\mu(A)=0$.